# Impimir columna de Excel con python, "openpyxl"

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Buen dia, tengo un proyecto en donde necesito imprimir toda una columna de un excel, Solo he logrado imprimir una especifica, Pero no tengo idea de como poder hacerlo con toda la columna,Dejo el condigo de lo que he logrado y espero me puedan ayudar, Gracias!

`````
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filesheet = 'C:\\Users\\acalobish\\Desktop\\Proyecto\\filtro.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filesheet)
sheet = wb.active
a2 = sheet['A2'].value
b2 = sheet['A4'].value
celdas = [a2,b2]
for cell in celdas:
   print(cell)
````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [`iter_rows`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) para iterar sobre una columna al completo. En tu caso, para la columna <kbd>A</kbd>:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import column_index_from_string

filesheet = 'C:/Users/acalobish/Desktop/Proyecto/filtro.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filesheet)
column = "A"

sheet = wb.active
ncol = column_index_from_string(column)
for cell, in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=ncol, max_col=ncol, values_only=True):
    print(cell)
```

Si quiere una lista con los valores y no solo imprimirlos:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import column_index_from_string

filesheet = 'filtro.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filesheet)
column = "A"

sheet = wb.active
ncol = column_index_from_string(column)
a_vals = [
    cell for cell, in sheet.iter_rows(
        min_col=ncol, max_col=ncol, values_only=True)
        ]
print(a_vals)
```